# How to continue a DB transaction across multiple ASP.NET Core action methods?

Tags: asp.net-core, http, entity-framework-core, transactions, state-management

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC application that requires continuing a database transaction across multiple action methods, but I'm facing architectural challenges due to HTTP being stateless.

Here's the scenario:

1. The first action method starts a transaction and performs some database operations. It then sends back a JSON response containing a check number for user confirmation.
2. The client receives this check number and presents a "Yes" or "No" dialogue to the user.
3. If the user selects "Yes", another action method is called which should continue with the same transaction started by the first action method.

Here's a simplified version of the code for the first action method:

```
[AjaxOnly]
public JsonResult StartTransaction()
{
    using (var transaction = smContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            var checkNumber = GetLastCheckNumber(smContext);
            
            return Json(new { CheckNumber = checkNumber });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
            return Json(new { Error = ex.Message });
        }
    }
}
```

Since the transaction is wrapped in a using block, it's scoped to the action method, and the transaction is disposed of when the action method completes. I need a way to persist this transaction so that it can be picked up in a subsequent action method after the user confirms with "Yes".

I understand that holding a transaction open across multiple HTTP requests is not recommended. However, the business logic requires this to be a single transaction for consistency.

Is there a pattern or practice within ASP.NET MVC that allows for handling this type of scenario? How can I maintain the transaction context between these separate requests while adhering to best practices for web applications?

I've tried using SessionHelpers and session variables with no luck due to the DbContext being unserialized.

Answer (score 1):

Challenges here will be things like concurrency and the fact that a user session can be abandoned at any time, so any design you come up with needs to accommodate this. A transaction across requests would be difficult, if not impossible to do reliably, and I wouldn't advise attempting it. The transaction or possibly even the DbContext would likely need to be managed at a static level to ensure each subsequent requests can work with the same DbContext instance or associate a DbContext instance to a common transaction, and even then I believe it would require sticky sessions as static references are not shared between web servers. Sticky Sessions alone won't help since each request is still a separate lifetime scope for the DbContext, it just tries to ensure the same server instance continues follow-up requests.

The options I can suggest are to use session state, or use either a staging table or row state within the database.

With session session state you might query data such as a "Check Number" from the database, but record all actions to compose the final desired data state within the Session. If you have multiple web servers you will need a session manager, or employ sticky sessions. (A session manager is recommended for single web servers as well as this caters for maintaining state if the web server/app pool needs to cycle) The downside of this approach is server session memory usage depending on how much data is maintained per user, and handling concurrency such as if you want to reserve something like a Check Number on a first-come-first-serve basis where subsequent requests get a different number. That requires updating state in the database or another source of truth that can check on reserved values, then handling scenarios where the user cancels an intended change, or abandons the change.

Using staging tables is essentially similar to session state where you write data as needed to separate staging tables in the database without relying on a over-arching transaction, then when the user goes to commit the changes, the data in the staging tables can be promoted into the real tables and the staging records can be deleted or marked as "processed" for historical purposes. The challenge with this approach is detecting and cleaning up abandoned actions that were started but never completed. Each staging record should have a timestamp and periodically a job would be used to locate and delete any staging  records that have expired.

Row state does something similar but reserves data rows to a particular session marker (could be user ID) where the record is marked at the beginning of the operation or created with a "pending" status, and is committed, reverted, or deleted depending on what the user does. (or again, if the changes appear to have been abandoned) This can work well with append-only type data structures where updates are treated as new versions of records. They can be reserved to be seen only by the user that initiated the changes (other read requests will continue to get the unreserved version) until the user commits the changes, after which the updated row is seen by everyone.

Hopefully that gives you some ideas on approaches for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this  if your second request goes to same server(with sticky session or affinity cookie) but you should not do this.
Transaction isolation level will lock the some of the record is the table during a write operation other users would be blocked.

Instead  create manual transaction like solutions like  use temporary tables  and add records and move records from that table to actual tables with a transaction on the second request.